# Find reduction formulas for the following indefinite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

my name is Rose and I am a Computer Science student.
I got this exercise for homework but i cant get to the solution.
Can someone please help me solve this exercise?
Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: Have you been given any guidance on how to set up a reduction formula?

Comment: @Ed_4434 No....

Comment: Then I will provide a detailed solution to one the questions from which you should be able to try the others.

Comment: You must at least show your attempts, however I give you a hint for your efforts are not in vain.

Hint: Use integration by parts several times.

Comment: @Ed_4434 yes I did, and I mange to do exercise number 18, but in exercise i cant get to Integeal of n-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea of a reduction formula is to provide a "general form" for integrals of a certain class so that repeated use is easy.  Take question number 19;

Let

$$I_n = \int x^ne^{ax}dx.$$

What we try to do is "reduce" this integral so that $I_n$ can be written in terms of $I_{n-1}$.

Recall the formula for integration by parts;

$$\int f(x)g^{\prime}(x) \ dx = f(x)g(x) - \int f^{\prime}(x) g(x) dx.$$

Let $ f(x) = x^n$ and $g^{\prime}(x) = e^{ax}$. Then, by the above formula;

$$I_n = \frac{1}{a}x^ne^{ax} - \frac{n}{a}\int x^{n-1}e^{ax}dx.$$

Now, we have $I_n$ in terms of $I_{n-1}$ and some other terms. Indeed, the above can be written

$$I_n = \frac{1}{a}x^ne^{ax} - \frac{n}{a}I_{n-1},$$

with $a \neq 0$.

In particular, this is useful when computing the integral for large values of $n$ (consider how many times you may have to integrate by parts for $n = 10$).

Try to set up reduction formulae in a similar way for the rest of the questions.

Comment: No problem, do you understand the steps?

Comment: yes I did, and I mange to do exercise number 18, but in exercise i cant get to Integeal of n-1

Comment: $\mathbf{Hint}:$ consider the fact that $\cos^n(x) = \cos(x) \cos^{n-1}(x)$

Comment: You will end up with $I_n$ in terms of $I_{n-2}$.